# The "open configuration file" for Bitcoin Core does not open

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf

Why doesn't the "open configuration file" in Bitcoin Core open when I click on it?

Settings -> Options -> Main, open configuration file at bottom left -> Configuration options.
It asks me to continue or cancel, but the file does not open.

ubuntu
Bitcoin core ver. 24.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file doesn't exist until you create it, for example by using the menu to make and save a change to the settings

Comment: 'Open Configuration File' option in GUI creates a blank `bitcoin.conf` file if it doesnt exist and open it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Do I need to set this up at the beginning? Or is the default fine if there is no special need?

Comment: @Luke Do you get any error when you click on "continue"?

Comment: No error message. Window just closes.

Comment: @Luke Sorry I have no clue. Please open an issue in https://github.com/bitcoin-core/gui/issues with more details, logs and screenshots

Comment: I will look into it from the link.
Thanks for your help.